# Android image can't convert to drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not able to add image. I downloaded the image and added it to res directory under drawable-mdpi. Then when I try to add the image on the view using imageView, it gives me this error

```
Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/ball01 
Failed to convert @drawable/ball01 into a drawable
```

Here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enlighten Me"
        android:id="@+id/button"

        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ball01" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: check the image file name and make sure it matches the name you specified in `@drawable\...` or check the extension of the image and make sure it is `jpg,png,jpeg...`

Comment: This sounds silly but did you Try refreshing your project folder after adding the image in your drawable folder?

Comment: this was it Niraj. I had to close the IDE and come back in...thanks

Answer (score 2):

The directory name should be 'drawable-mdpi'. Using a hyphen instead of an underscore.

Comment: sorry it was a typo..it actually is drawable-mdpi

Comment: so I still am looking for a solution

Answer (score 1):

image  name must   Digital or  lowercase 。   ide only identification.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, I had this image which I named Barcode and then saved it into my drawable folder, then I decided it would be better to have it named barcode with a small b, so I renamed it.
Then I checked if it would work, and I got the same errors as you, after changing the name in my xml to 'Barcode' with a big B, it worked.

solution for me: delete barcode image from drawable and add it again with the name I'm going to use for it, don't change the name while it is in drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on android studio. 
if you close and open project and it continues, all you need to do is RIGHT CLICK on the particular image you put in your "res" folder (that's giving the problem) and refactor-RENAME. Remove spaces in the name of the file. that should do it.